# Get data from column value using cursor to activity sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I am creating a song library connected to a database. The data is stored in a form (title, lyrics, urldelvideo) and added to a listview that only shows the title and id.

When selecting the listview item (in the listview it only shows the title) it sends me to an activity with two buttons to select to see the lyrics or to see the url of the video.

How do I pass the stored information to the activities of each item?.

In the DBHelper I have this code to get the lyrics of the song:

```
public Cursor getLyrics(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String sql = "select Lyrics from Songs";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);


    return c;
}
```

activity Lyrics I have:

```
lyrics_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);

    Cursor res = getLyrics();
    String str = "";

        if(res.moveToFirst()){
            str= res.getString(0);
        }

    lyrics_tv.setText(str);
```

Because I get the lyric of the first item in every item...

Answer (score 0):

You need to **id**entify which song to get the lyrics for.

You could change  the `getLyrics` method to be:-

```
public Cursor getLyrics(long id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String[] whereargs = new string[]{String.valueOf(id)};

    String sql = "select Lyrics from Songs WHERE id=?";
    return db.rawQuery(sql, null);
}
```

You use this in conjunction with extracting the **id** in the `onItemClick` method and pass this to the 2nd activity via an Intent Extra.

The **id** could be a column defined as an alias of the **rowid** column. e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE Songs (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, .....
```

or you could select use `rowid AS id` when obtaining the data for the Listview e.g.

```
SELECT *, rowid AS id FROM Songs
```

The specifics of how to extract the **id** from the Listview are dependant upon the source of the ListView.

You could also change `getLyrics` to return a string with the lyrics e.g. :-

```
public String getLyrics(long id){
    String rv = "no lyrics found";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] whereargs = new string[]{String.valueOf(id)};    
    String sql = "select Lyrics from Songs WHERE id=?";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        rv = c.getString(0);
    }
    c.close();
    return rv;
}
```

I would suggest considering not using rawQuery except when it is needed but rather making use of the convenience methods (the `query` method) and also trying no to use hard coded column offsets (i.e. the 0 in `c.getString(0)`) but instead using an offset derived from the column name, which is more flexible and less prone to causing errors.

As such and assuming returning the Lyrics for the song as a String I'd suggest :-

```
public String getLyrics(long id) {
    String rv = "no lyrics found";
    String whereclause = "id=?";
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(id)};
    String[] columns = new String[]{"Lyrics"};

    Cursor c = this.getWritableDatabase().query("Songs",columns,whereclause,weherargs,null,null,null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        rv = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Lyrics"));
    }
    c.close();
    return rv;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the field information is with:

```
if (res.getColumnIndex("Your field name") != -1) {
     str = cursor.getString(res.getColumnIndex("Your field name"));
   }
```